# Multiple XBEE talking to each other in API mode

Tags: xbee

I have 3 XBee s2 modules. one is the one that is always on and two others are on in specific time(first one is my ground station and second and third are two vehicles that will be on or off during mission)
I want the 2nd and 3rd XBee's to send telemetry data to 1st XBee which there is no problem in that.
but I have a problem when I want 2nd XBee talks to 3rd XBee as well...somehow it means all three XBee should be able to talk to each other ... Is there a way to implement this? because I should set SL-SH in xctu and since each XBee will be talking to more than one XBee I don't know how to set this addresses.

P.S:  I prefer using API Mode because i can get RSSI and source xbee adress.
P.S:There maybe many other xbees around  so i dont want to use broadcast mode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use API mode on all three devices, then the DH/DL settings don't matter.  You can address your frames using either the 64-bit MAC address, or 16-bit network address of the target device.  In addition, you can look at the source address of the received frames to know which device sent the message.

Comment: Can u give me an exaplme of how can iplement target adress for a frame?

Comment: XCTU has a frame generator you can use to create API frames for testing.  Take a look at this page: http://www.digi.com/resources/documentation/Digidocs/90001110-88/tasks/t_send_an_api_frame_from_the_third_xbee_module_to_other_modules.htm